# Display error text only for a specific amount of time?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I display a setError() only for specific amount of time?

```
if(editText.getText().length()==0)   
   editText.setError("please input text");
```

Can I make it disappear after some seconds?

Comment: This question doesn't even make sense.

Comment: use a second thread to set error to `null` after the fixed amount of time!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

Use Handler, in the OnCreate method, to keep a reference back to the UI thread from Non ui thread, because as soon as we create a Thread, we get dropped of the Ui thread.. sorry for the inconvenience for the left out line in the previous post. Now it will work as u wanted

```
   Handler h;

    onCreate(......) {

    h = new Handler();

    ....
    ....

    }


        if(editText.getText().length()==0) {  
           editText.setError("please input text"); 
           new Thread (new Runnable() {
              public void run(){
                 try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    h.post(new Runnable() {

                      editText.setText("");    // this will put the non-ui work on the ui thread back

                  }
                 }catch(Exception ex){}
              }    
           }.start();




  }
```

Comment: I belive this doesn't work because ediText will be set empty immediately after setError. The `editText.setText("")`  should be after Thread.sleep inside the thread.

Comment: Agree with @TiagoAlmeida I think you should use a postDelayed to automatically hide the setError after an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [toast notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).